# Asp.Net Core appsettings not found on production

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, debian

my app is working fine under debugging on my local machine. When I publish the app to my Debian Server it gives me this MySQL error:

> An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''.
> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failu

My appsettings.json:

> "ConnectionStrings": {
> "MyContext": "server=localhost;database=my_db;user=my_context;pwd=MyPWD"
> },

Does someone know why this is happening?

I've tried to rename the file to "appsettings.prod.json" but still not working.

Comment: is the db server installed where the connectionstring says it is?

Comment: Do you have an `appsettings.Production.json` file? Does it have an empty connection string in it?